# If two operators with all eigenvalues real numbers commute then both are triangularizable!

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $A,B:E\to E$, where $E$ is a finite dimensional vector space, be two linear operators such that all of the eigenvalues are real numbers.

> If $AB=BA$, prove that there exists a basis in which both the matrices of $A$ and $B$ are triangular.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/590772/81360) for one approach

Comment: Also, what have you tried?  What are your thoughts on the problem?